# How can I use a variable in a jinja2 selectattr filter?

Tags: python, enums, jinja2

I'm trying to filter a list based on an attribute. If I use the attribute as a string everything works fine:

```
{% set ys = xs | selectattr("type", "equalto", "first") | list %}
```

If I tried to use a variable (in my case a property of an enum) instead I get back an empty list

```
{% set ys = xs | selectattr("type", "equalto", MyEnum.FIRST) | list %}
```

The variable `MyEnum.FIRST` contains the string "first".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correctly passing in a variable, but if you now get an empty list, then `MyEnum.FIRST` does not produce the string `'first'`.

If `MyEnum` is a [`enum.Enum` subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum), then the attributes will be *instances* of that class. Use the [`.value` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes) to get an actual string value:

```
{% set ys = xs | selectattr("type", "equalto", MyEnum.FIRST.value) | list %}
```

Quick demo to show how enums work like and why you need the attribute:

```
>>> import enum
>>> class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
...     FIRST = 'first'
...     SECOND = 'second'
...
>>> MyEnum.FIRST
<MyEnum.FIRST: 'first'>
>>> MyEnum.FIRST.value
'first'
```

Comment: That worked! When I printed `MyEnum.FIRST` I got 'first' because `__str__` is defined to behave like that. The solution was to call `MyEnum.FIRST.value` as you wrote. My bad, thanks!

Comment: Saved me for sure! This is my code for getting data from a Map object ::

` {{ (maplst|selectattr('fduid','equalto',evnt.fduid)|list)[0].fdupl }} `